# change python directory from conda

Tags: python, ubuntu, miniconda

Recently, I installed miniconda, and because of which, my default python directory seems to have changed to,

/home/user/miniconda3/bin/python

Also, the default version seems to have changed to python 3.7 instead of python 2.7
And I cannot seem to install various libraries like tensorflow. 
How do I get my python back to normal?

Comment: is this what you get if you type which python?  /home/user/miniconda3/bin/python

Comment: this is after typing "which python" in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The miniconda installation has properly added itself to your `PATH`. You can check whether `/home/user/miniconda3/bin` is listed when you run

```
echo $PATH
```

in a terminal. If so, it most likely added some lines to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file. Simply remove these lines yourself, and your `PATH` should be back to normal (save the file and open up a new terminal), meaning that typing e.g. `python` will give you the system Python.